# Browser crashes while playing videos

Tags: video, browser, crash

I have a new PC (HP dv6t with integrated graphic card) with windows 7 installed. When i watch videos (youtube, divx, etc) the browser eventualy crashes. It happens after some time (15-60minutes) and then happens within 5 minutes, untill I restart the computer. It happens with all brwosers (IE8, FireFox and Chrome). Also, when I open up the msn games, MSN crashes. I have already tried reinstaling flash and the problem still persists. 
Any ideas? 
thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've reinstalled Flash, my next suggestion would be to reinstall your video drivers. Check HP's site for your particular model's drivers.

Remember, always uninstall existing video drivers before reinstalling (but make sure you're able to find the download before uninstalling).

Downloading from HP ensures that you have the latest version available. There may be a new version that corrects this problem or your current drivers are simply corrupt.